# Matching words in strings

Tags: php

I have two strings of keywords

```
$keystring1 = "tech,php,radio,love";
$keystring2 = "Mtn,huntung,php,tv,tech";
```

How do i do return keywords that common in both strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$common = array_intersect(explode(",", $keystring1), explode(",", $keystring2));
```

If you want them back into strings, you can just `implode` it back.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, interesting question... You can use this.

```
$arr1 = explode(',',$keystring1);
$arr2 = explode(',',$keystring2);
$duplicates = array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
foreach($duplicates as $word) {
    echo $word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `explode()` both strings on commas into arrays and loop through the first array checking to see if any of the words exist in the second array using the `in_array()` function. If so then add that word to a "common words" array.

Comment: rfw's answer here is more efficient, use that instead.

Answer (score -3):

Those are going to need to be arrays not variables.

```
$keystring1 = array('tech','php','radio','love');
$keystring2 = array('mtn','huntung','php','tv','tech');
```

First of all...

Comment: Not so much. (Technically, you're sort of correct, but `explode` takes care of that for you)